# Generic type vs rigid type in Haskell function

Tags: haskell

Why ghc doesn't complain about types being rigid in the following function?

```
play :: (Monad m, MonadIO m, Random a) => a -> a -> m a
play r1 r2 = do
  randomRIO (r1, r2)
```

In the above case, the `m` is actually `IO`. This code compiles. While othertimes, when I use a concrete type in a generic function, ghc complains that I am using a concrete type. Do I miss something here?

For example, if I say:

```
play :: (Monad m, MonadIO m, Random a) => a -> a -> m a
play r1 r2 = do
  randomRIO (1, 6::Int)
```

This time ghc complains that I'm using a rigid type. The thing that bothers me is that `IO` is in a way a concrete or rigid type because it's `IO` and not `Maybe`.

**Edit 1:**
Complete code that compiles without error:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
module Main where

-- showing how to program in the mtl style
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class
import           System.Random

type Game m a = (Monad m, MonadIO m, Random a, Show a)

-- step 1
play :: (Game m a) => a -> a -> m a
play r1 r2 = do
  yell "hi"
  randomRIO (r1, r2)
  --rollDice r1 r2

-- step 2
yell :: (MonadIO m) => String -> m ()
yell str = liftIO $ putStrLn str

-- step 3
rollDice :: (Game m a) =>  a -> a ->  m a
rollDice a1 a2 = liftIO $ randomRIO (a1,a2)

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn ""
-- main :: IO ()
-- main = do
--   play 1 (6::Int) >>= print
--   play 'a' 'z' >>= print
--   putStrLn "done"

Code that doesn't compile:

{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
module Main where

-- showing how to program in the mtl style
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class
import           System.Random

type Game m a = (Monad m, MonadIO m, Random a, Show a)

-- step 1
play :: (Game m a) => a -> a -> m a
play r1 r2 = do
  yell "hi"
  randomIO 'a' 'z'
  --rollDice r1 r2

-- step 2
yell :: (MonadIO m) => String -> m ()
yell str = liftIO $ putStrLn str

-- step 3
rollDice :: (Game m a) =>  a -> a ->  m a
rollDice a1 a2 = liftIO $ randomRIO (a1,a2)

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn ""
-- main :: IO ()
-- main = do
--   play 1 (6::Int) >>= print
--   play 'a' 'z' >>= print
--   putStrLn "done"
```

This doesn't compile:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
module Main where

-- showing how to program in the mtl style
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class
import           System.Random

type Game m a = (Monad m, MonadIO m, Random a, Show a)

-- step 1
play :: (Game m a) => a -> a -> m a
play r1 r2 = do
  yell "hi"
  **randomRIO (1, 6::Int)**
  --rollDice r1 r2

-- step 2
yell :: (MonadIO m) => String -> m ()
yell str = liftIO $ putStrLn str

-- step 3
rollDice :: (Game m a) =>  a -> a ->  m a
rollDice a1 a2 = liftIO $ randomRIO (a1,a2)

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn ""
-- main :: IO ()
-- main = do
--   play 1 (6::Int) >>= print
--   play 'a' 'z' >>= print
--   putStrLn "done"
```

**Update**

Just realized that my confusion comes from reading the wrong documentation of `random`
I was reading the `random-1.1` documentation while using the `random-1.2` in my code.

For people's reference:

```
random-1.1
randomRIO :: (a, a) -> IO a

random-1.2
randomRIO :: (Random a, MonadIO m) => (a, a) -> m a
```

Comment: You use `m a`, so that means `m` is something that takes a type, and then produces a concrete type. For example you can work with an `IO`, `Maybe`, `[]`, etc. Although here `Maybe`, and `[]` will of course not satisfy the `MonadIO` type constraint.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem if I say randomRIO (1,2::Int), ghc complains. So I can make `m` a concrete type, but not `a` ?

Comment: Why don't you share the code that *doesn't* compile, if you're not sure what's wrong with it? There's nothing much to answer here as it stands.

Comment: @daydaynatation: no, `IO` is not a concrete type. You can make an `IO Int`, `IO ()`, etc., but not an `IO`. `IO` is thus basically a function that takes a type (`Int`, `()`, etc.) and produces a type. `m` thus has kind `m :: * -> *`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ok I see, I thought IO is a rigid type...

Comment: "the m is actually IO". The code above doesn't require `m` to be `IO`. It allows `m` to be `IO` (or anything else that is `MonadIO`). So there is actually no problem if you call this code in a way that forces `m` to be `IO`. If you have some code that doesn't compile and you don't understand why, how about showing that code?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Please see my edit update

Comment: @RobinZigmond, Let me put the complete code and shows you that it does compile

Comment: To put it simply, in the second example, what type do you expect `play "abc" "def"` to have and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you are using [`random-1.2`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.2.0/docs/System-Random.html#v:randomRIO), which uses a more general type for `randomRIO`.

In that updated package, `randomRIO` is polymorphic both on the monad `m` and the value type `a`. Its type is:

```
randomRIO :: (Random a, MonadIO m) => (a, a) -> m a
```

So, when you write (renaming type variables for clarity)

```
play :: (Monad m1, MonadIO m1, Random a1) => a1 -> a1 -> m1 a1
play r1 r2 = do
  randomRIO (r1, r2)
```

GHC infers `m a ~ m1 a1`, which implies `m ~ m1` and `a ~ a1`, so `randomRIO` is called with those type parameters (`m` and `a` are *not* rigid here). Note that `IO` is not involved here at all: `m` could be `IO`, but could also be any other monad (in the `MonadIO` class).

Instead, when you write

```
play :: (Monad m1, MonadIO m1, Random a1) => a1 -> a1 -> m1 a1
play r1 r2 = do
  randomRIO (1, 6::Int)
```

GHC infers once again `m a ~ m1 a1`, hence `m ~ m1` and `a ~ a1`, but also infers `a ~ Int` since we are passing a pair of `Int`s to `randomRIO`. From `a ~ a1` and `a ~ Int` we infer `a1 ~ Int` which triggers the type error since `a1` *is* rigid.

If we instead had only a more specific type for `randomRIO` (such as the one we had prior to `random-1.2`)

```
randomRIO :: (Random a) => (a, a) -> IO a
```

then your reasoning would be correct: we would get `m1 ~ IO` during type inference, and that would cause an error since `m1` is rigid. We don't get this since `randomRIO` is more general.

Comment: Sorry, but I checked. randomRIO :: (a, a) -> IO a .  So randomRIO is a concrete type. see here: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html

Comment: May I know where you have found: randomRIO :: (Random a, MonadIO m) => (a, a) -> m a ?

Comment: Wow, just found that random-1.2 has an update compared with randome-1.1

Comment: 1.2 is almost a complete rewrite of random.

Comment: @daydaynatation Added a link to random-1.2 which has such type. I forgot it used to have the less general IO type.